# Too many quickcheck permutations for nested JSON

Tags: haskell, elm, quickcheck, fuzzing

I am following the example from this [blog](http://shmish111.github.io/2017/03/18/safe-json-with-haskell/) to test my JSON encoding/decoding and have run into an issue with deeply nested JSON.  The JSON structure has too many permutations to successfully test with quickcheck.  I ran into a similar issue with my client side Elm encode/decode fuzz testing.  I was able to overcome that by testing the two branches under the root node individually and then when testing the root node using constant values for the branches (because they were already tested).  Elm and haskell code are [here](https://gist.github.com/anotherhale/ba9fd29bf07b261f01037a54c553ebc3).

Is there a similar solution that I can apply to haskell?

Notes from my Elm code:

```
-- Initially `round trip table` attempted to fuzz test the entire table structure.
-- This was conuming massive amounts of memory (>1.5G) until the node process ran
-- out of memory.  To overcome this I fuzz test the board and sprite structures
-- individually and then fuzz test the table structure using Fuzz.constant on the
-- board and sprite lists so that it does not consume too much memory on the
-- already fuzz tested structures.
```

[Example Gist](https://gist.github.com/anotherhale/ba9fd29bf07b261f01037a54c553ebc3)

Comment: A large part of using QuickCheck (or other similar test generators) is controlling the size of the structures generated, trying to get meaningful coverage. See https://begriffs.com/posts/2017-01-14-design-use-quickcheck.html for an example of controlling the size. As a side note, I think testing that `(encode . decode) = id` is somewhat silly. Assuming your contained data doesn't violated, neither will your automatically generated instance. I would advise instead to make `personOptions :: Options` and make sure from FromJSON/ToJSON instances use these: that way both change when needed.